# How to prevent rendering

Tags: performance, mustache, handlebars.js

I use handlebars and dynamic provisioning of templates.

The template HTML for each form is put into the script tags and is downloaded runtime from the server. Eg:.

```
<script id="account-stats-template" type="text/html">
        <img src="img/ajax-spinner.gif" id="spinner-clickdesk-chats" style="display:none;"></img>
</script>
```

When the form is shown, I read html from script tag, compile using handlebars and then show it to the user.

I have a bundle of several such templates which I download.

However, I see that the browser actually tries downloading the src of images and sound files in text/html found in the script tags.

Is there a way to disable that?

https://gist.github.com/brendo/1857345 Gist perfectly explains the issue but doesn't recommend.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? I can't reproduce it in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.

Comment: It comes in Chrome Mac